# Strange query behavior oracle 11g

Tags: performance, oracle11g, connect-by, sqltools

I have a query as:

```
SELECT ps_node_id,name 
FROM cz_ps_nodes WHERE cz_ps_nodes.ps_node_type=261
START WITH NAME = 'Bundle Rule Repository',cz_ps_nodes.devl_project_id = P_devl_project_id AND cz_ps_nodes.deleted_flag = 0
CONNECT BY PRIOR ps_node_id = parent_id.
```

This query works.
But if I just remove the name from the select part like:

```
SELECT ps_node_id
FROM cz_ps_nodes WHERE cz_ps_nodes.ps_node_type = 261                       
START WITH NAME = 'Bundle Rule Repository',cz_ps_nodes.devl_project_id = P_devl_project_id AND cz_ps_nodes.deleted_flag = 0                                         
CONNECT BY PRIOR ps_node_id = parent_id.
```

The query just hangs but was working on oracle 10 g and the problem started when we upgraded to oracle 11g.
Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Which version and patch level of 11g? There are some bugs around performance. If you're patched-up then you might need to raise a service request with Oracle to investigate.

Comment: The PL/SQL Release is 11.1.0.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue solved by using : alter session set optimizer_features_enable='10.2.0.4' –